# Activity Save and Restore Instance State in partial visibility issue

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, savestate

I`ve faced that *Activity lifecycle* issue:

[image]

After`onPause()`Activity sets partially visible, than calls `onSavedInstanceState(Bundle)`, but when Activity sets to visible again calls just`onResume()`method.

The question is why calls`onSavedInstanceState(Bundle)`,if i can't get saved state Bundle in `onResume()`or`onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`*(because`onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`  is not called)*?

Comment: check the link under process lifecycle third point http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle. When activity is paused it is in background.

Comment: Raghunandan, thanks for answer. Please check this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#Create (on picture two higher options like i draw)

Comment: so what are you suggesting?

Comment: @ADK I highly recommend watching the [talk by Cyril Mottier at Droidcon Paris 2014](http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/09/25/deep-dive-into-android-state-restoration/). Here is the [video recording of "Deep Dive Into Android State Restoration"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekN2zvFytZk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that life-cycle methods after `onPause()` will be called but You may be sure all methods before `onResume()` will be if `Activity` is created/recreated. If only `onResume()` is called `Activity` was not destroyed/stopped and its state wasn't lost so You don't have to restore it.

As you can read in documentation about [restoring state](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState), `onRestoreInstanceState()` is called only if `Activity` was destroyed and [after `onStart()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).

Comment: but onSavedInstanceState() calls anyway?

Comment: Just in case, after it call onPause() it may be terminated without calling further life-cycle methods but state will be saved already.